# javafx how to center scrollpane content?

Tags: javafx, scrollpane

I've a tabview that contains a scrollPane, and a scrolPane contains nodes.
I added a button fit, i want when i click in this button the content of the scrollpane will be centered, I dont know how to do this

```
@FXML protected void onFitClicked(ActionEvent event)
{
      //calling the method that centers the content of the scrollpane
      fit();
}
```

that's what i've done until now .. :( i'll be happy for any help

```
public void fit()
{
    m_scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
    m_scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
m_scrollPane.setHvalue(0.5);
m_scrollPane.setVvalue(0.5);
```

Comment: @Uluk that doesn't work ... actually nothing happens , the content of the scrollpane desn't move to the center

Comment: @coeur, are the scrollpane's scrollbars scrolling to center?

Comment: @Uluk finally the reason why I can't center the content is that I'm already zooming the content so I can't perform the 2 actions at the same time. (changing the scale and centering)

Comment: @Uluk so what I'm planing to do is to scroll , but I'm having trouble how to scroll left and right ...do you have any idea?

Comment: @UlukBiy to scroll up and down I use this : m_scrollPane.getContent().setTranslateY(m_scrollPane.getContent().getTranslateY()+event.getDeltaY());   and it works perfect, but for left and right i do this : m_scrollPane.getContent().setTranslateX(event.getTotalDeltaX()); it doesnt work

Comment: @UlukBiy  finally I got it :D I did this and it works fine :  m_scrollPane.getContent().setTranslateX(m_scrollPane.getContent().getTranslateX()+event.getDeltaY()); Thank u , even if I feel i'm talking alone XD

Comment: @coeur, you were talking alone :). If you have read the javadoc of Hvalue and Vvalue properties of scorllpane, then you would see that these proprties are used for scrolling..